# jquery validations :i want to reset validations when i press reset button

Tags: jquery-validate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            /* <![CDATA[ */
            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery("#ValidNumber").validate({
                    expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Should be a number"
                });
                jQuery("#Email").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Should be a valid Email id"
                });
                jQuery("#ValidNumber").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL > 100) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Should be greater than 100"
                });
                jQuery("#Mobile").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[9][0-9]{9}$/)) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Should be a valid Mobile Number"
                });
            });
            /* ]]> */
        </script>
```

actually this is my script for jquery coming to my question  how can i reset  the validations along with the text fields when i press the reset button in a form whats the procedure involved in it.

Answer (score 0):

When you bundle your validation code into one validate call like this:

```
window.validator = $('form#your_formid').validate({
rules: {
    validNumber: {
        expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;"
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    // ...
},
messages: {
    validNumber: {
        expression: 'Should be a number'
    },
    email: {
        required: 'Fill in your email,
        email: 'Valid email please'
    }
}
```

You can call resetForm on de validate object when you click the reset button

```
window.validator.resetForm();
```